# Why do python functions have a __dict__?

Tags: python

In Python, functions created using `def` and `lambda` have a `__dict__` attribute so you can dynamically add attributes to them.  Having a `__dict__` for every function has a memory cost.  An empty `dict` uses 140 bytes in CPython 2.6.

Adding attributes to a function isn't a particularly common thing to do, and you can use a custom object with a `__call__` method for the cases where you do need a function with non-standard attributes.

Since adding custom attributes to a function isn't a common use case and having a `__dict__` has a memory cost why do Python functions have a `__dict__`?

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on the python-list mailing list?   http://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-list

Comment: Because Python doesn't go for efficiency in that way, it goes for power and useability. It saves MY time if I suddenly realize I want to add an attribute to an existing function -- I don't have to rewrite a bunch of code. If you want to save that memory, just have an empty dict you use for the purpose -- `func.__dict__ = my_empty_dict`.

Comment: @agf: you could even make a decorator for the task...

Comment: @Karl That sounds like the most convenient way. The question is, how many functions would you have to use it on to actually save memory? Or is there some persistent per-use memory involved, that would negate or reduce the savings?

Comment: A decorator can be written so that it re-points the function's `__dict__` and returns it, instead of a new object. Zero overhead. The original, empty `__dict__`s of the functions get GCd. The only cost is for the function that implements the decorator itself (and you can remove its own `__dict__` too, of course - or better yet, use its `__dict__` as the target for repointing!). Nice and simple. If I'm thinking straight, anyway.

Comment: Doesn't this also have to do with the fact that - ALL structures in Python (variables, methods, classes) are inherited from object and, as such, to remove a method's __dict__ you would actually have to create a separate parent for a method, apart from all other Python objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[PEP 232](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) has an extensive discussion about this, you might wanna take a look.

Answer (score 6):

> In Python, functions created using def and lambda have a `__dict__` attribute so you can dynamically add attributes to them.

Well, yes; they're objects, after all.

> Having a `__dict__` for every function has a memory cost. An empty dict uses 140 bytes in CPython 2.6.

It's 124 bytes for me. Not that it really matters for the sake of discussion.

If you really needed to save every byte, you wouldn't be using Python. In a program that uses a lot of memory, functions normally represent a tiny fraction of the number of objects, so the overhead is not really important. IMO you should be much more worried about the fact that it's costing you 16 bytes per floating-point value and you can't switch from `double` to `float`. Of course, the way to worry about this is to use Numpy. :)

> Adding attributes to a function isn't a particularly common thing to do,

If you come from the Java/C++/C# world, then I imagine it must seem horribly messy to you. But for people who come from the Perl/Javascript world (or even, in a rather different direction, maybe something like Scheme or Haskell), it's pretty elegant.

So basically, I would say the answer is "why not?" :)

Answer (score 3):

the empty dict doesn't exist if you don't require it, here is the code to check it:

```
import gc
f = lambda :1
print {} in gc.get_referents(f)
f.__dict__
print {} in gc.get_referents(f)
```