# Python overload primitives

Tags: python, overloading, forbiddenfruit

I'm trying to overload some methods of the string builtin.
I know there is no really legitimate use-case for this, but the behavior still bugs me so I would like to get an explanation of what is happening here:

Using Python2, and the `forbiddenfruit` module.

```
>>> from forbiddenfruit import curse
>>> curse(str, '__repr__', lambda self:'bar')
>>> 'foo'
'foo'
>>> 'foo'.__repr__()
'bar'
```

As you can see, the `__repr__` function as been successfully overloaded, but isn't actually called when when we ask for a representation. Why is that?

Then, how would you do to get the expected behaviour:

```
>>> 'foo'
'bar'
```

There is no constraint about setting up a custom environment, if rebuilding python is what it takes, so be it, but I really don't know where to start, and I still hope there is a easier way :)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve (that makes you want to overload built-in methods)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding special methods on an instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376604/overriding-special-methods-on-an-instance)

Comment: @goncalopp : What I'm trying to do is to have a running python shell in which the __repr__ called for any string is replaced by a custom method of mine. It doesn't have to be used in qny program that will have to run on any other python interpreter, so as I said, monkey-patching my own python would be fine, if only I knew the way to do it.

Comment: @njzk2 : I'm not trying to override the method on the instance, but indeed on the class. I tried with forbiddenfruit because python won't let me do it for a builtin type such as str.

Comment: once you've called `curse...`, what does `str.__dict__['__repr__']` tells you?

Comment: Also, what does `str.__repr__('foo')` returns?

Comment: I just though of this: isn't `__repr__` only called when you are trying to output something that is not actually an `str`? In the case of an `str`, isn't the object directly outputed?

Comment: str.__dict__['__repr__'] : <function __repr__ at 0xb72fc72c>, and
str.__repr__('foo') : 'bar'. Everything seems ok to me... And what do you mean by 'directly outputed' ? I tried with __str__ and it dosen't change anything.

Comment: Here is what it does with a list instead of str : >>> curse(list, '__repr__', lambda self:'bar')
>>> [].__repr__()
'bar'
>>> []
[]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62005/discussion-between-centime-and-njzk2).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing to note is that whatever `forbiddenfruit` is doing, it's not affecting `repr` at all. This isn't a special case for `str`, it just doesn't work like that:

```
import forbiddenfruit

class X:
    repr = None

repr(X())
#>>> '<X object at 0x7f907acf4c18>'

forbiddenfruit.curse(X, "__repr__", lambda self: "I am X")

repr(X())
#>>> '<X object at 0x7f907acf4c50>'

X().__repr__()
#>>> 'I am X'

X.__repr__ = X.__repr__

repr(X())
#>>> 'I am X'
```

I recently found [a much simpler way of doing what `forbiddenfruit` does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440694/whats-the-purpose-of-dictproxy) thanks to a post by [HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772649/hyry):

```
import gc

underlying_dict = gc.get_referents(str.__dict__)[0]
underlying_dict["__repr__"] = lambda self: print("I am a str!")

"hello".__repr__()
#>>> I am a str!

repr("hello")
#>>> "'hello'"
```

So we know, somewhat anticlimactically, that something else is going on.

Here's [the source for `builtin_repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/434673580106f4391da2c8937e646be579bc0c4d/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2530):

```
builtin_repr(PyModuleDef *module, PyObject *obj)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=988980120f39e2fa input=a2bca0f38a5a924d]*/
{
    return PyObject_Repr(obj);
}
```

And for [`PyObject_Repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7688b44387d116522ff53c0927169db45969f0e/Objects/object.c#L442) (sections elided):

```
PyObject *
PyObject_Repr(PyObject *v)
{
    PyObject *res;
```

```
    res = (*v->ob_type->tp_repr)(v);
    if (res == NULL)
        return NULL;
```

```
}
```

The important point is that instead of looking up in a `dict`, it looks up the "cached" `tp_repr` attribute.

[Here's what happens](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/989ae311fe6c6e3c8accb49942d0386e999cf1eb/Objects/typeobject.c#L2847) when you set the attribute with something like `TYPE.__repr__ = new_repr`:

```
static int
type_setattro(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *name, PyObject *value)
{
    if (!(type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE)) {
        PyErr_Format(
            PyExc_TypeError,
            "can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '%s'",
            type->tp_name);
        return -1;
    }
    if (PyObject_GenericSetAttr((PyObject *)type, name, value) < 0)
        return -1;
    return update_slot(type, name);
}
```

The first part is the thing preventing you from modifying built-in types. Then it sets the attribute generically (`PyObject_GenericSetAttr`) and, crucially, updates the slots.

If you're interested in how that works, [it's available here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/989ae311fe6c6e3c8accb49942d0386e999cf1eb/Objects/typeobject.c#L6548). The crucial points are:

- It's not an exported function and
- It modifies the `PyTypeObject` instance itself

so replicating it would require hacking into the `PyTypeObject` type itself.

**If you want to do so, probably the easiest thing to try would be (temporarily?) setting `type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` on the `str` class.** This would allow setting the attribute normally. **Of course, there are no guarantees this won't crash your interpreter.**

This is not what I want to do (especially not through `ctypes`) unless I really have to, so I offer you a shortcut.

You write:

> Then, how would you do to get the expected behaviour:
>
> ```
> >>> 'foo'
> 'bar'
> ```

This is actually quite easy using [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

> `sys.displayhook` is called on the result of evaluating an [expression](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-expression) entered in an interactive Python session. The display of these values can be customized by assigning another one-argument function to `sys.displayhook`.

And here's an example:

```
import sys

old_displayhook = sys.displayhook
def displayhook(object):
    if type(object) is str:
        old_displayhook('bar')
    else:
        old_displayhook(object)

sys.displayhook = displayhook
```

And then... (!)

```
'foo'
#>>> 'bar'

123
#>>> 123
```

---

On the philosophical point of *why* `repr` would be cached as so, first consider:

```
1 + 1
```

It would be a pain if this had to look-up `__add__` in a dictionary before calling, CPython is slow as it is, so CPython decided to cache lookups to standard dunder (double underscore) methods. `__repr__` is one of those, even if it is less common to need the lookup optimized. This is still useful to keep formatting (`'%s'%s`) fast.

Comment: This !  Thank you Veedrac ! It's perfect, with lots of explanations and all. I'm only half-way through but It's alreay more than I was hoping for.

Comment: It [does not work](https://gist.github.com/metaperl/99103cdfbe675afeaa38564ebcea7288)

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon Indeed, and I explain why it doesn't in this answer. It's likely I haven't been sufficiently clear, so if you'd explain why you think I've said otherwise it would really help me to fix up any ambiguities.

Comment: @Veedrac, would you mind having a look at this question, I wonder if what I'm trying to do is possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611050/python-change-exception-printable-output-eg-overload-builtins Thanks